# Jquery dynamically change select box value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form where i have two select box, second select box changes according to the first select box. Both select box is an array

example

```html
<div id="data-container">
<select name="first_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
<select name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="first_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
<select name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="first_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
<select name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>

</div>
```

[Please see the image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROsz0.jpg)

If I change the select box `first_select[1]`" I want to change the value of  `second_select[1]`

If I change the select box `first_select[2]`" I want to change the value of  `second_select[2]`

i can add more select box by clicking the add more button

Please see the image

Comment: You can use `:nth-child()` selector using jQuery and set the option.

Comment: And your question is ? Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see the image

Comment: Sorry this still looks more like a specification than a question. Can I remind you that SO is **not a free coding service**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should get you started:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="first_select[]"]', function(){
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('[name="second_select[]"]').val(currentValue);
});
```

The first thing I do is capture the value of the changed `first_select`. Then I traverse the DOM to the next `second_select` and change it's value to match the first one. This allows me to change pairs without knowing or needing the index of the changed `select`.

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sjy4zufa/)

This code also covers you "adding more" selects as I used [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to make sure the change event is captured as it bubbles up the DOM.

[Attribute Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)
[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)
[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

**EDIT**: OP changed the markup, requiring a different traversal of the DOM:

Given the following markup, where each drop-down is in a `div` having siblings:

```
<div>
  <select name="first_select[]">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="second_select[]">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The jQuery would have to be changed to this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="first_select[]"]', function () {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('[name="second_select[]"]').val(currentValue);
});
```

Here is the [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sjy4zufa/1/)

**EDIT** OP added yet another layer of complexity in the markup. Fortunately jQuery makes this easy, with only a couple of selectors needing changes. Here is the markup:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">                            
        <label>Designation</label>
        <select name="first_select[]" class="form-control author_designation" required="">      
            <option value="House Surgeon">House Surgeon</option>
            <option value="Medical Officer">Medical Officer</option>
            <option value="Private Practitioner">Private Practitioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select name="second_select[]" class="form-control author_type" >
            <option value="House Surgeon">House Surgeon</option>
            <option value="Medical Officer">Medical Officer</option>
            <option value="Private Practitioner">Private Practitioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The changes to the jQuery selectors come in the `.closest()` and `.next()` functions. I used the "starts with" selector on the `div`'s class:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="first_select[]"]', function () {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('[class^="col"]').next('[class^="col"]').find('[name="second_select[]"]').val(currentValue);

});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u4fmdzj7/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. If you change the markup this will not work because `.next()` is looking for a sibling. By placing them in divs you have effectively stopped them from being siblings. We would have to traverse the DOM in a different manner @Rakesh

Comment: See the updated answer @Rakesh

Comment: please see my jsfiddle //jsfiddle.net/mail2rakeshrk/u4fmdzj7/

Comment: Geez @Rakesh, why didn't you give me all of the markup to begin with? Next thing you're going to tell me is that the two divs are not next to each other.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Its working great :)

Answer (score 0):

give an dynamic id and data id to your select box once new select boxes add.

```
<select id="first_select_1" data-id="1" name="first_select[]">
<option value="option1">Option1</option>
<option value="option2">Option1</option>
</select>

<select id="second_select_1" name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
<select id="first_select_2" data-id="2" name="first_select[]">
<option value="option1">Option1</option>
<option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="second_select_2"  name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
<select id="first_select_3" data-id="3" name="first_select[]">
<option value="option1">Option1</option>
<option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="second_select_3" name="second_select[]">
 <option value="option1">Option1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

then add this below jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function(){
var data_val =$(this).attr('data-id');  
$('#second_select_'+data_val).val( this.value).change();
})

});
```

Comment: You can do this without adding to the markup.

Comment: Dear Jay Blanchard, I added some markup due He wanted add more select box. so please look his image link. OUsh you may use .next or sibling also.

Comment: Wanting to add more select boxes will not matter. See my example above.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard you are right . I did not identified you use .next() function. cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: i cant create dynamic id, i am using clone function on add more